# How to split 4113.52318N in two parts in php

Tags: php, string, split

I want to split 4113.52318N in two parts like
41 and 13.52318N
And after that I want to remove N from the second value.

any help please?

Comment: I'm sure you've tried something before asking here, let see it.

Comment: Not really very different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948904/how-to-convert-gps-coordinates-into-google-map-coordinates)

Comment: @MarkBaker it's actually different, I'd say the 2nd part ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, one is with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), i.e.:

```
<?php
$string = "4113.52318N";
$result = preg_match_all('/^(\d{2})([\d.]+)/', $string, $matches);
$partOne = $matches[1][0]; //41
$partTwo = $matches[2][0]; //13.52318
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/nR2wX8)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
$part1 = substr('4113.52318N', 0, 2) // 41
$part2 = substr('4113.52318N', 3);       // 13.52318N
$final = substr('4113.52318N', 0, -1);  // 4113.52318
```

Answer (score -2):

Use substr: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
$original = "4113.52318N";
$fortyone = substr($original, 0, 2); // 41
$other = substr($original, 3);       // 13.52318N
$n_removed = substr($other, 0, -1);  // 13.52318
```

Comment: can you tell me for "00131.93683E" this one please. Want to split in "001", "31.93683", "E".